# MathJax fails with semantics annotations

Tags: mathjax, mathml

MathJax fails to convert below mathml into SVG

```
<math>
  <semantics>
    <!-- Content MathML -->
    <annotation-xml encoding="MathML-Content">
    <apply><min/>
        <bvar><ci>x</ci></bvar>
        <condition>
        <apply><notin/><ci>x</ci><ci type="set">B</ci></apply>
        </condition>
        <apply><power/><ci>x</ci><cn>2</cn></apply>
    </apply>
    </annotation-xml >
  </semantics>
</math>
```

Does it failing because of incorrect encoding encoding="MathML-Content"?
What could be the reason behind the failure of MathJax.

Comment: You might want to add a note when you post to multiple forums.

Comment: I've down voted because your question does not provide enough information to give you an answer other than "it works for me".  You don't even say what "fails to covert" means.  Do you get a MathJax "Math Processing Error"?  Do you get a console error from MathJax?  Does any other math on the page process?  Are you using MathJax in a browser or mathjax-node?  What is the configuration you have used?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in [my response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/gkiro1Hgn84/uzZR09N8BQAJ) to your post in the MathJax forum, MathJax renders your expression perfectly fine.  I've included a snippet below that shows it rendering this expression into SVG.

```html
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    MathML: {extensions: ["content-mathml.js"]}
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=MML_SVG"></script>
   
<math>
  <semantics>
    <!-- Content MathML -->
    <annotation-xml encoding="MathML-Content">
      <apply><min/>
        <bvar><ci>x</ci></bvar>
        <condition>
          <apply><notin/><ci>x</ci><ci type="set">B</ci></apply>
        </condition>
        <apply><power/><ci>x</ci><cn>2</cn></apply>
      </apply>
    </annotation-xml>
  </semantics>
</math>
```

You have done something wrong on your end, but have not given us enough information to help you figure out what.  Cross posting here after your question was already answered in the MathJax forum is not likely to get you a better answer.

Comment: Can I load content-mathml.js dynamically from specific dir?

Comment: I mean to say, How can we load the extension from local file system?

Comment: I am loading mathjax dynamically in phantomjs, so when should I load extensions? I have tried to use MathJax.Hub.Config({
    MathML: {extensions: ["content-mathml.js"]}
  }); but no luck.